# web service java and C#

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I'm calling a .Net web service from my java code. The web service creates a C# object and serializes it as a byte array. So, in the Java side I just receive a byte array. I need to construct the original object (but as a java object) in the Java side. How can I do this?

Comment: Does the .net object contain any complex classes, e.g., a datareader?

Comment: ideally you dont. do you have any control over that c# web service? it should be returning some standard format like xml/json

Comment: The returned object is a simple object (Pojo) with five properties all String. unfortunately the web service serializes the object whole, no any standard are used.

Comment: It's not a POJO if it's coming from C#. radai has the right idea, you need to present it in a platform-agnostic format.